# Sorting by "last name" in MySQL when "full name" has periods in it

Tags: mysql, sorting

I found this nifty little order by condition that sorts strings of the type "First Last" nicely, even handling "First Van Damn" properly.

```
"SUBSTRING(p.name, LOCATE(' ', p.name) +1)
```

Now, I have some names in there like "Alfred E. Newman" and want the sorting to work properly for that name (ie it does not end up under E).

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: You have "Alfred E. Newman" but not "Richard Milhous Nixon"?

Comment: In this case we are dealing with baseball players, so I guess it also needs to work for "Juan Carlos Perez" to use a contrived example, sorted under P

Comment: Any chance you could clean up the database by adding real FirstName, MiddleInitial, and LastName columns? From there, your Name column can be a computed field based on those other three.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If you really want to do it, how about

```
RIGHT(p.name, LOCATE(' ', REVERSE(p.name)) - 1)
```

Answer (score -1):

I don't think you can do this automatically and reliably. For example, how would you automatically tell that Juan Carlos Perez goes on P and Richard Milhous Nixon goes on N?

You'll have to use heuristics and a dictionary of names or something similar, and that will always fail on some cases. It's best to do what Juliet says: process the data to generate candidates for review, and separate the name column into three (or four) columns: FirstName, MiddleInitial, LastName.